# Argument of type 'ISortPriority<any>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: angular, typescript

With my interface ISortPriority I am trying to assign keys to match that interface and then sort an array based on that. My sorting algorithm works I am just having issues using the interface.

Here is the test that I am running:

```
it('Should sort with multiple keys - Numbers', () => {
    const arr = [{name: 'j company', title: 'Software Eng 1', age: 23,company: 'test'}, {name: 'f company', age: 21, title: 'Software Eng 7', company: 'abc'},{name: 'g company', title: 'Software Eng 2', age: 22, company: 'test'}, {name: 't company', age: 24, title: 'Software Eng 3', company: 'test'}];
    const keys: ISortPriority<any>[] = [{sortKey: 'age', priority: 1}, {sortKey: 'company', priority: 3}, {sortKey: 'name', priority: 4}, {sortKey: 'title', priority: 5}];
    expect(sortArrayByKey(arr, keys)).toEqual([{name: 'f company', age: 21, title: 'Software Eng 7', company: 'abc'}, {name: 'g company', age: 22, title: 'Software Eng 2', company: 'test'}, {name: 'j company', age: 23, title: 'Software Eng 1', company: 'test'}, {name: 't company', age: 24, title: 'Software Eng 3', company: 'test'}]);
});
```

But when I call:

```
expect(sortArrayByKey(arr, keys))
```

It is saying: "Argument of type 'ISortPriority[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '"title" | "name" | "company" | "age"'." When hovering above the "keys" parameter

Finally, here is the sorting method and the interface that I am using:

```
export function sortArrayByKey<T>(ordersArr: T[], sortByKeys: keyof T): T[] {
    return ordersArr.sort((a, b) => {
    return sortWithKey(a, b, sortByKeys, 0);
});
}

function sortWithKey<T>(a: T, b: T, keys, index: number) {
    index = index || 0;
    keys = keys.sort((c, d) => (c.priority > d.priority) ? 1 : -1);
    const currKey = keys[index].sortKey;
    return a[currKey] > b[currKey] ? 1 : (a[currKey] < b[currKey] ? -1 : 
    sortWithKey(a, b, keys, index + 1));
}


export interface ISortPriority<T> {
    priority: number;
    sortKey: keyof T;
}
```

Comment: Can you fix the code formatting in your question?

Comment: Yeah I went ahead and updated it. Sorry, still getting use to TSLint and stuff.

Comment: what's T here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I see is in the typing of your parameter sortByKeys in the following

```
export function sortArrayByKey<T>(ordersArr: T[], sortByKeys: keyof T): T[] {
    return ordersArr.sort((a, b) => {
        return sortWithKey(a, b, sortByKeys, 0);
    });
}
```

above you are saying that sortByKeys must be of type keyof T, but then in your code you are trying to pass it ISortPriority[].

below are the changes I think you should make to get this working

```
export function sortArrayByKey<T>(ordersArr: T[], sortByKeys: ISortPriority<T>[]): T[] {
    return ordersArr.sort((a, b) => {
        return sortWithKey(a, b, sortByKeys, 0);
    });
}

function sortWithKey<T>(a: T, b: T, keys: ISortPriority<T>[], index: number) {
    index = index || 0;
    keys = keys.sort((c, d) => (c.priority > d.priority) ? 1 : -1);
    const currKey = keys[index].sortKey;
    return a[currKey] > b[currKey] ? 1 : (a[currKey] < b[currKey] ? -1 : 
    sortWithKey(a, b, keys, index + 1));
}
```

the only changes being that I have typed your sortByKeys parameter in the first function and the keys parameter in the second function to both be ISortPriority[].

I think this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

your second param of sortArrayByKey is

```
sortByKeys: keyof T
```

Which means that that has to be one of the 4 keys of of the objects that you're passing in the first parameter, which are: title, name, company and age.

I think you've just incorrectly typed that parameter because you're passing in all of the keys along with their priority.  So I think that the signature of sortArrayByKey should be like this:

```
function sortArrayByKey<T>(ordersArr: T[], sortByKeys: ISortPriority<T>[]): T[]
```